# How to get Envelope Distort to fill shape without leaving empty space in it in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

[image: The shape is not fully filled]

[image: I can try to fill the empty space left manually after doing "reset with mesh" but I want this to be automatic]

[image: If I only use text, it will get extended without leaving empty space]

I can try to fill the empty space left manually after doing "reset with mesh" but I want this to be automatic.
If I only use text, it will get extended without leaving empty space.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's no way to automate it. Illustrator knows nothing about anything. It's only a dumb machine. If you distort a group of objects, it distorts the whole group and is unaware of anything contained within it.  It knows nothing about the text, or the space around objects, or anything about your design, or what it ought to look like.

Comment: If it can extend only text perfectly until the edges of the path/shape, as you can see it in the screenshot., why does it leave empty spaces when it's fitting graphics + text?

Comment: I already told you. You are comparing its application to a group, versus applying it to text only.  Illustrator doesn't know what it is distorting.

Comment: Perhaps you could distort the text and its container separately, however this is even more manual work, two meshes instead of one.  Alternatively with just one mesh, you could manually distort the text by moving the mesh points inside the shape, so there isn't so much space.

Comment: [see example here](https://imgur.com/FNGOaZK)

Comment: dragging mesh anchor points to the edges to fit the empty spaces left  didn't have a good result, I tried it, it's too much distortion like that

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KihIkL6EGg4&t=91s see? the fitting should be perfect, those are 2 fixed shapes just like in my case, yet the fitting is perfect, no gaps left

Comment: Looks to me like it's *not* actually a group before distortion.. but more like you are just selecting multiple objects then applying the envelope. Group everything first, then envelope.

Comment: Results are the same if it's a group or not, rasterized or not or if the appearance is expanded or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not actually work the way you think it does. It does a transformation from rectangle to shape, not arbitrary shape to arbitrary shape. And the rectangle is just the bounding box of your shape. Since there's no functionality for giving it a rest shape there is no way you can do this on a slanted box.

[image]

**Image 1**: All envelope distort modes start with a rectangular shape. So the things outside the object is most decidedly part of the object as far as Illustrator is concerned.

You can however in this case first slant it to a rectangle, then distort. But that just for this particular shape it will fail in most other cases.

[image]

**Image 2**: If you unslant it first you get a better, though not perfect result.

To recap what you ask can not be done with the tool you ask to do it with. Mainly because it starts out with the bounding rectangle and any non rectangular shape has empty shape.

Comment: Great find, I figured this out already yesterday evening, I forgot to check back here yesterday. Now it's clear. Question still remains though: can Illustrator be fooled to think that the empty areas in the frame are not empty? I would also need a bit theory as to how Illustrator distinguishes frames from paths. Often I have a path inside a frame, if I select it with the direct selection tool, the path is getting selected, if with the normal selection tool, then the frame. Can Illustrator be instructed to ise the shape (the path) for the envelope and not the frame?

Comment: The use case for me is that I am filling "empty" areas in large spread size images with text. So I want graphical text boxes with text background and illustrative vector parts, that will adapt to the free space available in images that were assigned for text. I am more an author than a graphic artist (making magazines) so I am buying the graphical text boxes, I just need to mold them to take up the shape of my free spaces in my images. I have not seen this much, just got this idea.

Comment: @AdamAlleman No theres no functionality to start with other than recrangle. Your goal however does not seem to require envelope distort for anything.

Comment: Then how do you fill an arbitrary area with a graphic that has a totally different shape originally? Anything else than envelopes?

Comment: @AdamAlleman you draw it. Alternatively you don't. Depends on your onlook on life really. Theres no magick mechanism. But in this case drawing it is hardly a really big deal.

Comment: @AdamAlleman Is this what your after?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dmEx.png or do you really need text to be distorted too?

Comment: No i only need graphical text boxes that are not just a background color in a shape. So for example for a quote I can mold a pre made graphical quote box like that in an arbitrary shape. The text will be inserted later and it will not be distorted.

Comment: @AdamAlleman So like my link then. Draw a shape copy shape, make into strroke change color offset copy. insert quotes with white of knockout background done

Comment: You are getting off topic. I said I want to mold pre-made graphics into arbitrary shapes.

Comment: @AdamAlleman You cant. Theres no generic mechaism for what your asking. Each situation needs to be handled with a case by case basis. Sorry no functionality in illustrator that solves this issue. Hire an artist or find another software.

Comment: Envelopes work fine for me for this purpose (as demonstrated), so far the original fill graphic is rectangular or if it can be made rectangular.

Comment: @AdamAlleman Lol

Comment: Well it works with everything, including rasterized content, expanded content, all kind of content within a frame, so it's nice.